# Dominoes game - bones path algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, html5-canvas

I'm trying to done a JS domino game and I'm running some issues draw the path of the bones.

Basically, I use a tree system for the dominoes. But it's complex for me to arrive to rend correctly on the layout the path.

If I just render the layout like on the tree, it's simple but when I reach an edge of the board I have to rotate the bone and continue.
When I rotate, I apply the same rotation the all of the child of this bones (and the child of the child) etc...

The issue is when I get a spinner (node) with several branches from it. Sometime, and after several rotation, one branch cross over another branch or even the same branch.

I tried to find a solution like an algorithm to calculate all of the positions from a tree on a physical layout and I found something about semi-hamiltonian path but I'm not sure how to use it.

If somebody have an idea about that, it would be awesome.

Sorry for my english.

(Edit)
This is a screenshot of a typically issue that I get:

[image: bones paht]

The goal is to find a way to calculate every bone positions from a tree and rend them on my canvas layout. I need to take care of the edge limitation and when a line/row cross over a bone.

Comment: Its hard to understand what is your goal and what you already have done. A screenshot of your curent situation would be helpful to understand the problem itself.

Comment: Thks, Tamas, I just added a screenshot.

Comment: There's no easy solution to this problem, and AFAIK no standard algorithm for solving it. Human players solve the problem by rearranging tiles into serpentine paths. Or by simply leaving a gap in a path and continuing the path somewhere else on the board.

Comment: This game: https://dominoes.playdrift.com is doing a good job for that.